# Is there anything like "template sheet" in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm looking for a solution of following problem:

I would like to have multiple sheets each one (one sheet should correspond to one company) would contain data like "date, product, price" and several statistics.

It is easy to create one sheet and copy the result to other sheets and adjust it for given companies. The problem is with changes in future they would need to be done in multiple places and I don't really like the idea.

Is this possible in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but if all your sheets are in one workbook, select all the sheets and then do the changes: the changes will happen on every selected sheet.

Comment: Especially useful for formatting jobs.

Comment: Extremely important to remember to select a single sheet (that is, unselect all sheets) after completing this task, so the next routine data entry doesn't overwrite data on all sheets, as I usually do

Answer (score 1):

I might not be understanding, but you could easily do this just w/ formulas. Have one sheet w/ your base template; and in other tabs just refer back: "=!Template_Sheet"

You can also refer to other files this way.

Then again, might not be understanding the question.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post a link to a spreadsheet?

Comment: I know I can refer to other sheets but I'm not sure if I can refer to other sheet to use the formula in current sheet

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to do is set up one master price sheet and link the cells to it on any other sheets where the prices are listed.  Then, you can just change it on the price sheet and it would change on every sheet.

I did something similar when having to create a combined materials and labor page for every product in my company.  I had one page that listed the labor costs for every process the company did and linked to it on every other product page for labor costs and also had a master material sheet and linked to it for all of the material costs.  That way, when labor or material costs went up all I had to do was change the labor and material pages instead of hundreds of pages for all of the products.  You could do the same and set up a sheet or particular cells on a master sheet for any data which might change over time.